# How connection pooling works with RedisTemplate using spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-redis

I have the following code snippet which for getting the RedisTemplate.

```
@Bean
public JedisConnectionFactory getJedisConnectionFactory() {
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName(host);
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword(RedisPassword.of(password));
    }
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(port);
    return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration, getJedisClientConfiguration());
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(getJedisConnectionFactory());
    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    return redisTemplate;
```

}

My question how sprint-boot will understand the Connection pooling because I have not provided any information in my factory about the connection pool. My application properties file has the following properties.

```
redis.host=<redis-host>
redis.port=<port>
redis.password=<password>
redi.jedis.pool.max.total=16
redi.jedis.pool.max.idle=8
redi.jedis.pool.min.idle=4
```

Comment: Can you share details for this `getJedisClientConfiguration()` as well.

Comment: @Bean
 public JedisClientConfiguration getJedisClientConfiguration() {
  JedisClientConfiguration.JedisClientConfigurationBuilder builder = (JedisClientConfiguration.JedisClientConfigurationBuilder) JedisClientConfiguration
    .builder();
  GenericObjectPoolConfig GenericObjectPoolConfig = new GenericObjectPoolConfig();
  GenericObjectPoolConfig.setMaxTotal(maxConnection);
  GenericObjectPoolConfig.setMaxIdle(maxConnectionIdle);
  GenericObjectPoolConfig.setMinIdle(minConnectionIdle);

  return builder.usePooling().poolConfig(GenericObjectPoolConfig).build();

 }

Comment: What are the default values set if no pooling values are specified?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create `JedisClientConfiguration` using the builder

```
JedisClientConfigurationBuilder builder = JedisClientConfiguration .builder()
```

this will internally call default constructor on `JedisClientConfiguration` which looks like something like this.

```
private DefaultJedisClientConfigurationBuilder() {
  this.poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
  // other configs
}
```

`JedisPoolConfig` further extends `GenericObjectPoolConfig` which has default values as below. (which would be default values if not overridden manually)

```
maxTotal = 8;
maxIdle = 8;
minIdle = 0;
```

In your case, as you have overridden config with `GenericObjectPoolConfig`, it will pick values from there.

```
GenericObjectPoolConfig.setMaxTotal(maxConnection); 
GenericObjectPoolConfig.setMaxIdle(maxConnectionIdle); 
GenericObjectPoolConfig.setMinIdle(minConnectionIdle);
```

As you are specifying `usePooling()` and `poolConfig(genericObjectPoolConfig)`, your app will use these config for connection pooling.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Lucid for the detailed explanation. Can you point me to some document where I can read it completely and understand it better in future

Comment: @Parveen you can check the official documentation here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:connectors. Along with you can also go through source code. You can also go through jedis https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis